# Does anyone have a link to a plugin or tutorial that can make me a jquery/ajax image slider/carousel like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I really like how cnn.com implements this. I can REALLY use it on the website I am making. What makes it so cool is the page numbering, and the first, previous, next and last buttons. Notice how you get an image preview when you hover over a number...nice!

Anyone with a link to a website that shows how to implement this? I will be calling images and other information from a database.

Link to the cnn page:

http://edition.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/africa/02/10/egypt.protests/index.html?hpt=T1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI, that's done in Flash. It sure is possible to do something similar in Javascript though. In fact, there are a ton of slideshow plugins and scripts already out there. Have you tried searching for one?

Comment: @deceze. I have spent this week looking for something like this but nothing comes close. I would rather not use flash. Maybe my searching techniques leave a lot to be desired lol. If you have a link to something similar in javascript:plugin, tutorial, please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these pages. They have LOTS of different ones to choose from.

- http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/
- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/10/20-stunning-jquery-image-sliders-and-tutorials-for-creating-your-own.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had been through that site already. Good stuff but not exactly what I need.